# react native maps does not display the map correctly

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I have installed react-native-maps in my app but when i enter a MapView this is the output :

[image]

I followed the installation guide on [github](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md) and entered the api key, but still does not display anything.

this is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <MapView
         style={styles.map}
         region={{
           latitude: 41.89193,
           longitude: 12.51133,
           latitudeDelta: 0.015,
           longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
         }}
       >
       </MapView>
     </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
   height: 400,
   width: 400,
   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   alignItems: 'center',
 },
 map: {
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
 },
});
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem or what does it depend on?
thank's

Comment: Try to use `initialRegion` instead of `region`

Comment: I tried with initialRegion, unfortunately it returns the same result. @oma

Comment: your implementation seems correct, maybe your internet connection is weak, it seems that the content is not downloaded. Can you try it with an emulator ?

Comment: I tried with an emulator but it returns the same result and anyway my connection at the moment is 80mbps in download @oma

Comment: And your google map Key is set correctly ?

Comment: now it works but the strange thing is that it displays the map only if I use customMapStyle @oma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183185/discussion-between-oma-and-v-cozzatella).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add *provider* to MapView:

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
....
<MapView
     provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
     style={styles.map}
     region={{
       latitude: 41.89193,
       longitude: 12.51133,
       latitudeDelta: 0.015,
       longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
     }}
   >
</MapView>
```